# Javascript/Typescript Constants with a WebPack called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a constants file:

**`collections.ts`**

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {Chat, Message} from 'api/models';

export const Chats = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>('chats');
export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection<Message>('messages');
```

My problem is I get the following error at run time:

> ```
> Error: There is already a collection named "chats"
> ```

The reason is because I have two other files that invoke `collections.ts` to access the `Chats`.

**`methods.ts`**

```
import {Chats, Messages} from './collections';
```

**`chats.ts`**

```
import {Chats, Messages} from 'api/collections';
```

**Question**

How do I solve this issue? I thought `constants` could be invoked multiple times without re-instantiating themselves.

As you can see here from *Chrome Developer Tools*, it is called twice at run time:

[image]

I think my problem is the webpack (I got from [this tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup)) is creating two `collections.ts`.

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
var camelCase = require('lodash.camelcase');
var upperFirst = require('lodash.upperfirst');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var isRelease = process.argv.indexOf('--release') > -1;

var config = module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.ts',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/www/build/js',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  externals: [
    'cordova',
    resolveExternals
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      api: __dirname + '/api/server'
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};

if (isRelease) {
  config.plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false }
    })
  ];
}

function resolveExternals(context, request, callback) {
  return meteorPack(request, callback) ||
    cordovaPlugin(request, callback) ||
    callback();
}

function cordovaPlugin(request, callback) {
  var match = request.match(/^cordova\/(.+)$/);
  var plugin = match && match[1];

  if (plugin) {
    plugin = camelCase(plugin);
    plugin = upperFirst(plugin);
    callback(null, 'window.cordova && cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.' + plugin);
    return true;
  }
}

function meteorPack(request, callback) {
  var match = request.match(/^meteor\/(.+)$/);
  var pack = match && match[1];

  if (pack) {
    callback(null, 'window.Package && Package["' + pack + '"]');
    return true;
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1332) is someone with the same problem. But I am still not sure how to fix it. in `app.bundle.js` I can find similar code to modify, but this is generated code, so don't see how this would help.

Comment: Can you check that Meteor isn't trying to load both TypeScript and transpiled JavaScript files? Is your IDE transpiling your TS as you go along? In that case you'd be best off deleting the transpiled JS as you don't need them and are causing duplicated code.

Comment: Hi Aron, Thank you for your reply.  Please excuse my ignorance, but I am not sure. How do I tell if the IDE (Visual Studio Code) is transpiling the TS code to JS? I am also not sure where to delete? I did try delete `app.bundle.js.map`, because it appeared to have the code in it that called `collections.ts`, but it was just regenerated again. I am running Ionic2 & Meteor, so possibly `ionic serve` generated the file.

Comment: The easiest way to test is to add a console.log inside collections.ts and see if it appears in the command line more than once.

Comment: Yes it does (if the console.log is above the export where it fails the 2nd time). I can also tell from Chrome Dev Tools that it hits a breakpoint there twice. The stack trace indicates it's from the two imports above.

Comment: Why do you think it is creating two `collections.ts`? I am sure that's my problem.   I am using a `webpack` (which I don't really understand) as I am following this tutorial: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup

Comment: Hm if they're both running from TS files then it's probably not caused by loading both TS and JS.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the picture above, `collections.ts` and `collections.ts?97d5` are called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123272/discussion-between-richard-and-aron).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

By making `node_modules` a symbolic link, i.e. only having one `node_modules`, fixed this.